# BASH : Difference between '-' and '--' options

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, ls

I was working my way through a primer on **Shell (Bash) Scripting** and had the following doubt :

> - I came across the **`ls`** command
> - The **`man`** page of **`ls`** lists a few use cases as :
>
>   **`ls -a`**
>
>   **`ls --block-size='M'`**

***My Question :***

> - What is the difference in `-` and `--` ?
> - Why are there 2 nomenclatures used ?
> - What is the motivation behind it ?

Comment: Not exactly related but comes close , http://superuser.com/questions/372203/whats-the-difference-between-one-dash-and-two-dashes-for-command-prompt-paramet

Comment: Not a bash question at all -- `ls` is an external command; it behaves the exact same way no matter what program calls it, whether or not that program is a shell.

Comment: I am sorry @CharlesDuffy , I did not know that ls is an external command - am a newbie :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Long-form (`--foo`) options are a GNU extension -- something present in GNU `ls`, but not present at all in the POSIX standard setting requirements for UNIX tools, so other versions of `ls` are not obliged to support these options. The entire word (`foo`) is meaningful in this case. This nomenclature was added more recently, and is more expressive than the short form (and doesn't have namespace limitations).

Short-form options (`-al`) are, at least in form, standardized (though extensions can add new ones). They're handled character by character, one letter at a time -- so `-al` means `-a` (show hidden files) and `-l` (long output), rather than having `-al` have its own meaning in this case. This is the original syntax for UNIX command-line options, and is thus supported not only for terseness but also for backwards compatibility.

Comment: can you , please , explain in slightly more detail - I am unable to really grasp as to what you mean ;)

Comment: @pranav, could you be more specific about what to clarify? Is it what I mean by "character-by-character", or what I mean by "GNU extension", or something else?

Comment: Hi , @CharlesDuffy , I am unable to understand : GNU Extensions , "character-by-character" , long form vs short form and "at least in form" . Sorry , if I am a pain in the posterior :)

Comment: This is perfect @CharlesDuffy , thanks a ton :) Can I take this opportunity to ask you if you can suggest some resources for a beginner like me to become really proficient at Linux , Bash etc. ... would be grateful :)

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide (and other content on the same wiki -- the pitfalls page and the FAQ are particularly useful) is a good place to start.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your answer is what I understood... but I am now looking at options for the `find` command which do not seem to follow the pattern.  For instance, "find -iname" is not "find -i -n -a -m -e" ... the word "iname" is its own, unique option.  

I guess `find` command is an exception to the rule?  (working on OSX)

Comment: @Manningham, `find` actually *does* comply with POSIX syntax guidelines, because in the POSIX standard version of `find`, at least one directory name is mandatory -- you *must* use `find . -iname`, not just `find -iname` -- and per the POSIX utility syntax guidelines (but unlike GNU's more lenient implementation), everything past the first argument is *also* a positional argument, not an option. So all the `find` actions and filters -- `-iname`, `-print`, etc -- are specified as positional arguments, not options at all (which makes sense, as they're ordering-sensitive).

Answer (score 2):

They both achieve the same task: passing parameters to the program being called. There aren't many ways of doing that nor a standard way: those are the two main ones known as short option and long option (GNU style).
A program does not need to implement them both, although the way it's usually done lets handling them as unique.

Comment: Formally, there *is* a standard way (in the "standards-body ratified and published" sense), although it only is binding on POSIX-compliant utilities (a set which includes `ls`).